# overlapping and enumerate in python

Tags: numpy

Given two files
We need to find of all the number overlapping the data from both the file which are prime.

For check the prime number we need to develop a function  called check_prime and use the same.

My code :

```
import math
def is_prime(num):
    if num == 1:
        return False
    if num == 2:
        return True
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

one = []

theFile = open("One.txt", "r")
array = []
for val in theFile:
    array.append(val)

print(array)

theFile = open("Two.txt", "r")
array1 = []
for val in theFile:
    array1.append(val)

print(array1)

for i in array:
   one.append(i)


print(one)
```

Comment: Looks like your code is incomplete, can't see `is_prime` called from anywhere

Comment: I can see 9, 10 etc in your output, so first check whether your prime function is working properly or not? If yes then look into your logic of creating the third list.

Comment: That is the problem. The prime function is working fine but the program altogether fails to give correct output. Any suggestions on where I am going wrong? @anuragal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there but here are the missing bits in your code:

**1) Reading from the files**

To avoid writing twice the same code to open both files, and to handle more than two files, we can loop through the file names instead of opening each one separately

*So instead of:*

```
theFile = open("One.txt", "r")
#[...]
theFile = open("Two.txt", "r")
```

*We could use:*

```
file_names = ['One.txt', 'Two.txt']
for i in file_names:
    theFile = open(i, "r")
```

**2) Extracting the numbers from the files**

Then you extract the values in the text file. The list of numbers in each file gets imported as a list containing a string with numbers in it.

So there are 2 things we need to do:

1) extract the string from the list
2) read each string number in the list separated by commas.

*If you do:*

```
for val in theFile:
    array.append(val)
```

You will only append one list containing one string to your `array`.

In your code, you create two lists: `array` and `array1` but then only loop through the `array` list which puts in your `one` list only the data from the `array` list, not using `array1` at all. Nothing to worry about, I also get confused sometimes between `array[1]` and `array1` if I name several lists ending in 1,2,3.

*So instead we could do:*

```
for val in theFile:
    array = array + val.split(",")
```

We use `+` because we want all the number-strings in one single list and not one list containing several lists (you can try to replace this by: `array = array.append(val.split(","))` and you'll see you get a list containing lists but what we want is all number-strings from all files in one single list so better to concatenate the elements in the lists into one single list.

Now that you have your array list that contains all string-numbers from your text files, you need to transform them into **integers** so you can run your excellent `is_prime` function.

So we create a second list that I've called `array2` where we will store the string-numbers as integers and not as strings.

The final output that you want is a list of the unique prime numbers in both text files, so we check that the number is not already in `array2` before appending it.

```
for nbrs in array:
    if int(nbrs) not in array2:
        array2.append(int(nbrs))
```

Almost there! You've already done the rest of the work from there on:

You need to pass all the unique numbers in `array2` to your `is_prime` function to check whether they are prime or not.

We store the result of the `is_prime` function (`True` or `False`) into the list `is_nbr_prime`.

```
is_nbr_prime = []
for i in array2:
    is_nbr_prime.append(is_prime(i))
```

Now, because you want to return the number themselves, we need to find the indexes of the prime numbers to extract them from `array2`, which are the indexes of the `True` values in `is_nbr_prime`:

```
idx = [i for i, val in enumerate(is_nbr_prime) if val] #we get the index of the values that are True in is_nbr_prime list  
unique_prime_nbrs = [array2[i] for i in idx] # we pass the index to array2 containing the list of unique numbers to take out only prime numbers.
```

That's it, you have your unique prime numbers in the list `unique_prime_nbrs` .

If we put all the steps together into two functions, the final code is:

```
def is_prime(num):
    if num == 1:
        return False
    if num == 2:
         return True
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1):
         if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def check_prime(file_names):
    array = []
    array2 = []
    for i in file_names:
        theFile = open(i, "r")
        for val in theFile:
            array = array + val.split(",")    
        for nbrs in array:
            if int(nbrs) not in array2:
                array2.append(int(nbrs))

    is_nbr_prime = []
    for i in array2:
        is_nbr_prime.append(is_prime(i))

    idx = [i for i, val in enumerate(is_nbr_prime) if val]    
    unique_prime_nbrs = [array2[i] for i in idx]

    return unique_prime_nbrs
```

To call the function, we need to pass a list of file names, for instance:

```
file_names = ['One.txt', 'Two.txt']
unique_prime_nbrs = check_prime(file_names)
print(unique_prime_nbrs)
[5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 23]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of stuff you need to do:

- When reading the text from the input files, convert it to integers before storing anywhere.
- Instead of making `array` a list, make it a set. This will enable testing membership in much shorter time.
- Before storing a values from the first file in `array`, check if it is a prime, using the `is_prime` function you wrote.
- When reading the integers from the second file, before adding the values to `array1`, test if they are already in `array`. No need to heck for prime-ness, because `array` would already contain only primes.
- Finally, before outputting the values from `array1` you would need to convert them back to strings, and use the `join` string method to join them with separating commas.

So, get to it.

Comment: I tried but it is showing errors.Can you please show the changes in my code @Amitai Irron. Thanks:)